# Hot to get a role through reactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

const FPP = message.guild.roles.find(FPP => FPP.name === "FPP");
const TPP = message.guild.roles.find(TPP => TPP.name === "TPP");

const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;


if(command === "roles") {
const embed = new RichEmbed()
  .setTitle('Verfügbare Rollen')
  .setDescription(`

    ${FPP.toString()}
    ${TPP.toString()}

  `)
  .setColor(0xdd9323)
  .setFooter(`ID: ${message.author.id}`);

  message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {

    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('');

    msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
      max: 5,
      time: 15000,
      error: ['time']
    }).then(collected => {

      const reaction = collected.first();

      switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        case '':
            message.member.addRole(FPP).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              return message.channel.send(`Error: Rolle konnte nicht hinzugefügt werden. Wende dich bitte an den Admin dieses Servers.`)
            });
            message.channel.send(`Du hast dir die Rolle **${FPP.name}** hinzugefügt`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
            break;
        case '':
            message.member.addRole(TPP).catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
             return message.channel.send(`Error: Rolle konnte nicht hinzugefügt werden. Wende dich bitte an den Admin dieses Servers.`)
            });
            message.channel.send(`Du hast dir die Rolle **${TPP.name}** hinzugefügt`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
            break;
      }

    }).catch(collected => {
      return message.channel.send(`Konnte dich der Rolle nicht hinzufügen.`)
    })

  })
}
```

This is my command I'm working on. Somehow it works but not in my desired result.
I want that the user on my Discord can assign themself a role.
For now only the user that used this command can assign himself a role through a reaction.

That is probably because of this line.

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
```

For some reason that role gets assigned but only after 30 Seconds and not instant.

But what I really want is that everyone who reacts to this command gets that role. Not only the author. I already tried to just get rid of that part. But then the command doesn't work anymore.

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

This is for if you're only using this on a single server. You'll need to modify it for multi server use.

```js
<CLient>.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;
  const member = reaction.message.member
  switch (reaction.name) {
    case "emoji_name_1":
    member.addRole("roleID").then((res) => {
      // You can do something like this, or nothing at all. Your choice.
      reaction.message.channel.send(`You've been given the \`${res.name}\` role!`)
    }).catch(console.error);
    break;
    case "emoji_name_2":
    member.addRole("someOtherRole").then((res) => {
      reaction.message.channel.send(`You've been given the \`${res.name}\` role!`)
    }).catch(console.error);
  };
})

<CLient>.on("messageReactionRemove", (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;
  const member = reaction.message.member
  switch (reaction.name) {
    case "emoji_name_1":
    member.removeRole("roleID").then((res) => {
      // You can do something like this, or nothing at all. Your choice.
      reaction.message.channel.send(`You've been removed from the \`${res.name}\` role!`)
    }).catch(console.error);
    break;
    case "emoji_name_2":
    member.removeRole("someOtherRole").then((res) => {
      reaction.message.channel.send(`You've been removed from the \`${res.name}\` role!`)
    }).catch(console.error);
  };
})
```

Of course this is really basic, so you'll need to modify this anyways. It'll check for whenever the reaction is added/removed and not just on a single message. I suggest making a store of message ids or something to check for or something. If you do it your way it won't track reactions after the bot has gone down and back up, unless you want it that way.